# `ts()` has converted my daily data to a wrong daily series

Tags: r, plot, time-series

This is the CCMP Index. **R** produces a wrong graph. It never took a dip. The graph in **Excel** shows it correctly. The data in CSV file has no problem, so what did I do wrong?

```
ccmp <- read.csv("/Users/jackconnors/Downloads/yeet.csv")

ccmp$time=as.Date(ccmp$date, format ="%m/%d/%Y")

ccmp=ccmp[order(ccmp$time), ]

### Find the Date Range

ccmp_min_date = min(ccmp$time)

ccmp_max_date=max(ccmp$time)

### TS variable

ccmp_ts=ts(ccmp$price ,start=c(2012, 7), end=c(2022, 7), frequency=365)
View(ccmp_ts)

plot(ccmp_ts, xlab="Year", ylab="Price", main="CCMP Prie", lwd=2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Without having access to the data or making your code reproducible, I don't know how we can help you.

Comment: @Jack Is there any update? What did you find out based on my answer?

Answer (score 2):

This can be diagnosed even without access to your data. Knowing the real length of your series, i.e., `length(ccmp$price)`, is sufficient. But basically, your following usage of `ts()` is wrong.

```
ccmp_ts <- ts(ccmp$price, start = c(2012, 7), end = c(2022, 7), frequency = 365)
```

By specifying `start = c(2012, 7)` and `frequency = 365`, you tell `ts()` that there are 365 data in each year and the series starts from day 7 in 2012. By specifying `end = c(2022, 7)`, you tell `ts()` that you want to get `365 * (2022 - 2012 + 1) + 1 = 4016` out of your series `ccmp$price`. Check `length(ccmp_ts)` to verify this.

But what if `ccmp$price` has fewer data than this? Well, data will be recycled. This is what happened to you. The figure clearly shows that data in 2019 ~ 2022 are identical to data in 2012 ~ 2015.

Usually we never specify `start` and `end` at the same time when doing `y <- ts(x, ...)`, as they will exactly imply the length of the resulting series.

- If `y` is shorter than `x`, then `x` will be truncated, which is fine;
- If `y` is longer than `x`, your series will be recycled, which causes problem.

By omitting either `start` or `end`, the other will be auto-determined based on `frequency`. All data in `x` are kept: no truncation or recycling. The resulting `y` is identical to `x`.

So, to make your code run without problem, you can drop either `start = c(2012, 7)` or `end = c(2022, 7)`.

But working code does not mean everything. Believe it or not, although you can pass any positive value into `frequency`, only 1 (evenly spaced series), 4 (quarterly series) and 12 (monthly series) have natural interpretation. When you pass other values, you need to make sure it is a sensible period. Here, 365 is not a good one for day of year, because leap years have 366 days.

I can only imagine two situations where using `ts()` for daily time series is reasonable.

1. Daily series grouped by week, i.e., `frequency = 7`. So time can be interpreted as Monday, Tuesday, ..., Sunday.
2. Daily series with no grouping, i.e., `frequency = 1`. So time is simply interpreted as day 1, day 2, etc.

If you want to identify daily series with full time information, like year, month, etc, you have to use package **zoo** or **xts** to create a "zoo" object or "xts" object.